# How to get permission to remove a directory in PowerShell ?

Tags: powershell

When I want to remove the directory  `c:\cygwin`  in Windows 7, I Input the command in PowerShell and get this error:

```
remove-item c:\cygwin  -recurse

+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (grodvi.exe:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

How can I get permission to do that?

Comment: Run it under administrator (elevated privileges).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running PowerShell as administrator (right-click, Run as Administrator).

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on PowerShell, then click `Run as administrator`, the shell opened should allow you to execute the command.